# CiviMail - Unable to select group, getting error of No recipients

Tags: civimail

After update from 4.7.23 to 4.7.24 Unable to select group, getting an error of No recipients, under Wordpress 4.8.1.

My steps:
Create new mailing  Mailings>New Mailing 
The new mail opens.
Click on Recipients, the dropdown is empty, no groups listed.

This no problem in WP demo site.

I've read a lot of similar bugs posts with no solutions. 
I have several mailing groups, I can manage in other places in CiviCRM.

With the update get some exception on my CiviCRM, caused by wrongly set permissions on files and folders (writable by groups).

This can be caused by other wrong permissions?

Comment: I'm unclear from your question how to trigger the error.  Could you please edit the question to give step-by-step instructions for triggering this problem?  Also, do you see the same problem on the demo site at wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Answer (score 1):

Because you update so frequently, it's easy to track down the potential issues.  I see two relevant changes to CiviMail's recipient list: [CRM-20521](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20521) and (maybe) [CRM-21070](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21070).

In non-technical terms: Prior to Civi 4.7.24, all the mailing groups were loaded onto the mailing form when you selected "New Mailing".  For sites with many groups, that made things slow.  In 4.7.24+, the list is loaded after the page is loaded, in a more efficient way.

First, look at the screenshot on CRM-21070: Does your "Recipients" box [look like this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/secure/attachment/63870/cm-missing%20recipient.png)?  If the box is present, but has no data, the issue is related to CRM-20521.

If this is caused by CRM-20521, then you have a JavaScript problem.  That could be a bug, but more likely means your Resource URLs are incorrect.  Please consult [troubleshooting JavaScript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850) - in particular, check your browser's dev tools Network/XHR tab for errors - and you should find your solution.  If you find an error but you're not sure what to do, please edit this question with the errors you find.

Answer (score 1):

I switched back to 4.7.23 to send mailings.

The problems not as in CRM-21070, the box exist. 
Maybe the Recipient.js not firing up.

Thanks for your help. If I have more time, I will update CiviCRM in next week, and update this post.

Another try, no success, but helped more to figure out more details. it is a  CRM-20521 related. The field is filled by database query results, the query stops by DB error: Syntax error.

From my log:

Sep 24 16:54:34  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

```
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => REPLACE INTO       I_4041 (email_id, contact_id)

                SELECT      civicrm_email.id as email_id,
                                    civicrm_contact.id as contact_id
                FROM                civicrm_email
                INNER JOIN          civicrm_contact
                        ON          civicrm_email.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id
                INNER JOIN          civicrm_group_contact
                        ON          civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_group_contact.contact_id
                INNER JOIN          civicrm_mailing_group
                        ON          civicrm_group_contact.group_id = civicrm_mailing_group.entity_id
                            AND     civicrm_mailing_group.entity_table = 'civicrm_group'
                LEFT JOIN           X_4041
                        ON          civicrm_contact.id = X_4041.contact_id
                WHERE
                                   (civicrm_mailing_group.group_type = 'Include')
                    AND             civicrm_mailing_group.search_id IS NULL
                    AND             civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Added'
                    AND             civicrm_contact.do_not_email = 0
                    AND             civicrm_contact.is_opt_out = 0
                    AND             civicrm_contact.is_deceased <> 1
                    AND             (civicrm_email.location_type_id = )
                    AND             civicrm_email.email IS NOT NULL
                    AND             civicrm_email.email != ''
                    AND             civicrm_email.on_hold = 0
                    AND             civicrm_mailing_group.mailing_id = 549
                    AND             X_4041.contact_id IS null
                    GROUP BY civicrm_email.id, civicrm_contact.id
                ORDER BY civicrm_email.is_bulkmail, civicrm_email.is_primary [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
                    AND             civicrm_email.email IS NOT NULL
  ' at line 22]
```

In demo civicrm's  no such errors.